# Correct use of @CompoundIndex and MongoRepository

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm getting quite slow query respone so I'm wondering if I'm creating the compound mongo index and using it effectively with the MongoRepository and how to verify the indexes are working effectively.

```
@CompoundIndexes({
    @CompoundIndex(name = "onwebsite_process_sequence", def = "{'additionalfields.onwebsite': 1, 'additionalfields.process' : 1, 'additionalfields.onwebsite': 1}")
})

public class DdsJson {
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
  @JsonProperty("additional_fields")
  AdditionalFields additionalfields = new AdditionalFields();
...
}


public class AdditionalFields {

  public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AdditionalFields.class);
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
  @JsonProperty("sequence")
  @Indexed
  private Integer sequence;
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
  @JsonProperty("process")
  @Indexed
  private Integer process;
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
  @JsonProperty("onwebsite")
  @Indexed
  private String onwebsite;
}

public interface DdsJsonRepository extends MongoRepository<DdsJson, Integer> {
         
Page<DdsJson> findByAdditionalfields_OnwebsiteAndAdditionalfields_SequenceAndAdditionalfields_Sequence(String onwebsite,int process, int sequence, Pageable pageable);
        
         
}
```

Regards
Conteh

Comment: You can verify if a index is being used by running the `explain` method on a query.

Answer (score 0):

> how to verify the indexes are working effectively.

Two ways here ...

1. Cover your code by a load test. Run a version without the index and with an index. Say insert 10 million records in there and try to do some reads. Follow this [guide](https://rieckpil.de/mongodb-testcontainers-setup-for-datamongotest/) to setup an integration test and then time it.
2. You can add the index and then read the query plan following this [guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/analyze-query-plan/). It will allow you to know if your index will be used or not.

So there you go ... an experimental and a theoretical solution. I'd suggest exploring both. Gives you a good background to tackle a problem like this in the future.